# jQuery ui close button is not shown but it works properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using the jQuery-ui dialog and I have added the libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

But when the dialog box appears, you can not see the close button X.

I can see it as this:

[image]

And I have these errors at the console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

[image]

Comment: you need to download the images specified in the error. it means the images are not present in your project

Comment: If you use jquery ui then kindly download the full package..

Comment: which theme should I download to have regular blue close button ?

Comment: Try this ,http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you download the Jquery UI zip file and unzip it, there is a images folder. Copy and paste in your project folder. Then, it will work flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

### Errors:

> There's 3 pngs that you do not have on your server.

You can point to the pngs at:

## [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqueryui)

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png
>
> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/images/ui-icons_555555_256x240.png
>
> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/images/ui-icons_777777_256x240.png

#### OR

> download them and place them on your own server.

In both cases you may have to change the ruleset in either the 1. stylesheet or 2. inline `<style>` tag on your HTML file:

1. **stylesheet:** `jquery-ui.css` lines. To find those specific lines to edit, go to that error log and click each error. You should be redirected to the browser's view of the CSS file to the exact line that you need to edit.

#### OR

2. **`<style>...</style>`** within the `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

image file is not its original place kindly download required image of plugin and retry below code

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your project ui-icons images to be placed in images folder under content folder